# Changing CPU governor of a rooted android device

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, root, android-kernel

I'm developing an application which changes the CPU Governor of the rooted device. I know that I can get the current governor in "sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor", but how do I change it?

Comment: This might be better asked on http://android.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Thanks. I'll post it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, from the directory you are, do:

```
# cat scaling_available_governors
```

Then you will get the output something like this:

```
ondemand userspace powersave performance
```

These are the governors your kernel supports. Now you can force the kernel to use one of them by running:

```
# echo "powersave" > scaling_governor
```

You will need root for this to work.

Comment: Does this change persist reboots? If not, are you aware of any that does?

Comment: @SteelBrain these changes are not persistent